# wordcloud2 in R with figPath

Tags: r, wordcloud2

I am working on a word cloud shaped by an image on a jpg or png file. I am using R and its wordcloud2 package with figPath option.

Issuing the following command:

wordcloud2(Word_more_freq,figPath = "unicorno.jpg",size = 1.5, color = "skyblue"),

where Word_more_freq is a data frame and its columns are words and freq (words' frequency), sometimes no image is displayed and other times I can just view the image without the words. No error message is raised.

Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Francesco

Comment: Without the data and the image, there is no way to answer this question. Since the `figPath=` points to an image to be used as a mask, it seems possible that a .jpg file would not work. You can ask the package maintainer by using the command `maintainer("wordcloud2")` which will return the email address of the package maintainer.

Comment: Thanks very much, dcarlson. The url of the image is https://craftelier.com/media/catalog/product/cache/a097d745ed9b0eefd1efdb902cde6ff1/p/r/pr-arthf1079_copie.jpg. Anyway I will follow your suggestion, try and ask the package maintainer why it is not showing anything but the mask itself. I don't know whether it is useful but I am able to build simple wordclouds just using my data and the wordcloud package. Cheers, Francesco